# XML layout code for the Android contacts pop-up

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm looking for the XML layout code that produces the look and feel of the People contact details pop-up in Android 4.0. Here's a screenshot to illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

I've been looking at Grepcode without much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single XML file, but I think you want to look at how all of the `quickcontact_` stuff is tied together in [platform_packages_apps_contacts / res / layout](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/tree/master/res/layout).

Comment: Thanks, a combination of these seem to be what I'm looking for :-)